# What is real issue with the NSData in my code 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

I want to send json service when the user search text on searchbar. Here the issue  is that I return null value of NSData object, what the issue is here? If I define the same url which I print in console that works but what's the issue here?

```
-(void)doIt{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:weburls];
    NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [self getData:data];
}
```

If I will write like that then it works, but I want to call the service on the searchbar event but there is a problem

```
NSString *weburl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
@"http://192.168.1.196/ravi/iphonephp?mname=",searchText];
NSLog(@"%@",weburl);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:weburl];
NSLog(@"the url is : %@",url);

NSError *error;

NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:nil error:&error];
NSLog(@"Data is :%@",data);

NSLog(@"the Error massage is : %@",error);
[self getData:data];
```

Gives me console value like

```
customCellDemo[1553:f803] the url is : http://192.168.1.196/ravi/iphonephp?mname=a

2012-03-16 15:26:36.259 customCellDemo[1553:f803] Data is :(null)

2012-03-16 15:26:43.624 customCellDemo[1553:f803] the Error massage is : Error 
Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" 
UserInfo=0x6ab2760 {NSURL=http://192.168.1.196/ravi/iphonephp?mname=a}
```

Comment: use `+ (id)dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)aURL options:(NSDataReadingOptions)mask error:(NSError **)errorPtr` [(documentation)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-BCIIDGEC) and check the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the manual of dataWithContentsOfURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:);

> Return Value: A data object containing the data from the location
>   specified by aURL. Returns nil if the data object could not be
>   created.

In other words, it can either not create an NSData (unlikely) or it can probably not get any data from your supplied URL. I suggest you try to use [`dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:) instead to get an error code and be able to diagnose the problem.

Comment: this url run in my browser essily the problem is here i cant add in NSData object

Comment: @sai-info.iphone Does it run in your iPhone browser?

Comment: ya in my phone (simulator) browser is also run and return me json String

Comment: @sai-info.iphone Then you'll probably have to test with the version of the call mentioned in the answer that gives you an error code back.

Comment: if i have to #difine the same url then its work so is there issue in version ??